# How can i passing response of axios to variable outside the axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I wan't to fill the variable outside the axios in array type and then export the array to another file.

navigation.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
/* eslint-disable */
let menus
axios.get('https://api.link/', {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}` } 
})
.then(res => {
  menus = res.data
})

/* eslint-enable */
export default menus
```

index.js

```
import navMenu  from './navigation'

// Array of sections
export default [...navMenu]
```

api results

```
[
  {
    "Oid": "3b05b576-fa95-11eb-84d0-00163e01a21d",
    "Name": "Menu",
    "Icon": "BookIcon",
    "Submenu": [
      {
        "Oid": "3b05b576-fa95-11eb-84d0-00163e013r46",
        "Name": "Submenu",
        "Link": "link/to/page",
        "Icon": "BookOpenIcon"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

or maybe give me the solution to export array from api to index.js

Comment: You're working with Vue.JS ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to wrap your axios call as a function and use its return value rather than exporting the menu variable.

```js
    async function makeRequest() {
    
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.link/', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}` } 
        })
    
    return response.data
    }
```

and you can call that function as follows:

```js
    makeRequest().then((data) => {
    //do something with data
    }
```

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but there is an example of what I suggested:

App.js

```js
    import getDataFromServer from "./navigation";
    import { useState } from "react";
    
    function App() {
      const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);
    
      const callServer = async () => {
        let result = await getDataFromServer();
        setMyState(result.data);
        console.log(myState);
      };
    
      const listItems = myState.map((item) => <li>{item["title"]}</li>);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={callServer}>Call Server</button>
          <ul>{listItems}</ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

In another module e.g. (navigation.js)

```js
    import axios from "axios";
    
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    export default async function getDataFromServer() {
      const result = await axios.get(url);
      return result;
    }
```

The example uses sample API from jsonplaceholder site:

```
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
```

The bottom line, your alternatives are:

1. If your data reside in an external module, you can follow the
   intuition I suggested above.
2. If you are passing data from a parent component to a child component, you can use `props`.
3. If you are passing data from a child component to a parent component, you can use `callbacks`.
4. Or you can look into `useContext` or look into other state
   containers (redux) to see how you can share data between the different
   components in an app.

Comment: how can i export the array inside index.js file ?